# HttpClientBuilder issue : Could not initialize class sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$CustomizedTLSContext

Tags: java, ssl

In my java code below, I randomly receive the following error.

```
 final HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
         final HttpGet request = new HttpGet(requestParameters);
         final HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

Error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$CustomizedTLSContext
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:291)
    at java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(Provider.java:1848)
    at java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1824)
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:236)
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:164)
    at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:168)
    at org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts.createDefault(SSLContexts.java:51)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:977)
```

I can't reproduce the issue as it is random. Does that mean that the ssl/tls handshake has failed?

would Implementing a retry policy help remediate this issue ?

```
  public DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler() {
        this(3, false);
    }
```

https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.2/source-code/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler.java

Below are the java libraries I am using :
[image]

**UPDATE**: While I thought I would get rid of this issue by moving from the [HttpClientBuilder](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.html) to the  [java.net.HttpUrlConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html), unfortunately, I am getting the same error :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:291)
    at java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(Provider.java:1848)
    at java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1824)
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:236)
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:164)
    at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:168)
    at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault(SSLContext.java:99)
    at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(SSLSocketFactory.java:123)
    at java.base/javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory(HttpsURLConnection.java:335)
    at java.base/javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.<init>(HttpsURLConnection.java:292)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.<init>(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:95)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:62)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:57)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:1051)
```

Comment: It does not mean SSL handshake has failed. The error is while loading SSLContext which happens much before SSL handshake. NoClassDefFoundError indicates that the class was available at compile time is not available at run time. The class which is missing comes from jsse.jar which is available with JDK. Which version of Java you are using?

Comment: See my added libraries screenshot

Comment: Can you provide a complete stack trace?

Comment: This is the full stack trace from the moment I call .build()

Comment: Something is failing with SSL Context initialization. You will have to play around.
You can try to set the ssl parameters explicitly as per the article https://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-ssl

Answer (score -1):

My Java version was 1.8.0_171. By upgrading to 1.8.0_261, same problem was solved.

Comment: My Java version is 1.8.0_261 and I still experience the issue